# Attach CSS triangle to MatTooltip depending on actual positioning?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design, tooltip

I've been wrecking my brain to figure out a way to attach a little CSS triangle to a `MatTooltip` in Angular that switches from being at the `top` when the tooltip is displayed below the host element (default) to being at the `bottom` when the tooltip is above the host element (e.g. when the host element is too close to the bottom of the viewport).

> Am I missing some property that would give me a way to switch the CSS
>   class? Or is it simply impossible?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is possible.**

Since MatTooltip controls its positioning via `transform-origin`, you can make use of it.

For example, `.mat-tooltip[style*="transform-origin: left center"]` only selects tooltips shown to the right of its parent, so you can display the triangle on the left side of the tooltip.

**Values of `transform-origin`:**

- Tooltip to the right of its parent: `left center`
- Tooltip to the left of its parent: `right center`
- Tooltip above its parent: `center top`
- Tooltip below its parent: `center bottom`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @Oliver would you consider marking it as an answer then?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Although you can use css to draw pointed triangle to `mat-tooltip` but you cannot move its position according to View-port/DOM view like above or below, So Its not possible to move the pointed triangle.

**Solution:**

> I have used SAT Popover for styling tooltips. You can give it an
>   angular component and it will display as you style it.

https://ncstate-sat.github.io/popover/

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Add the mat CSS class "matTooltipClass="below"" in HTML control.

Step 2 - Add the below CSS class in you CSS file.

```
.mat-tooltip {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom-color: white;
    color: black;
    margin: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9f9fa3;
    height: auto;
    &::after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        border-left: 0.5rem solid transparent;
        border-right: 0.5rem solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 0.5rem solid rgb(132, 56, 56);
    }
    &.below {
        overflow: initial;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        &:after {
            top: -0.5rem;
            right: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
            transform: rotate(0);
        }
    }
    &.below[style*="center bottom"] {
        overflow: initial;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        &:after {
            top: calc(100%);
            right: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
    }
}
```